# Side-by-side boxes; one static width, one variable width, vertically aligned bottom

Tags: jquery, css

I need to position two boxes side-by-side within a variable width container. One box has a width defined, the other needs to fill the rest of the space.  Also, the boxes need to be vertically aligned: bottom.

```
CSS
==============
body { background-color: papayawhip; }
.container {
    background-color: white;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.box-fixed {
    background-color: lightgray;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
}
.box-flexible {
    background-color: lightcoral;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 200px; /* <-- Don't want this! */
}

HTML
==============
<div class="container">
  <div class="box-fixed">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="box-flexible">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</div>
</div>
```

I could use floats and overflow:hidden, but then I lose my vertical align bottom.  And tables would be bad.

Comment: Can you create an image of what you would expect this to look like?

Comment: Take a look at the top of my personal website: http://www.rkostin.com/about-robert-kostin.html I'm trying to make the site responsive.  The width of the red "card" on the left is supposed to stay static. The width of the text to the right of the card is supposed to be flexible. Also, the design requires the text to align to the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed it using jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/uvvdN/1/

It's not perfect, I had to add the `+ 4` to `_fixedWidth` purely because of time but I hope this is the sort of thing you are after.

Comment: Ahh... yes. The dreaded 4px white space between HTML elements occurs when lining up inline-blocks. I can work with that!  But I was hoping for some esoteric CSS-only solution that probably doesn't exist.  Cheers! (rmk)

Comment: I imagine the only other way you could do it with just CSS is using [CSS Expressions](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/css-expressions-in-ie-and-scoping) but these are really not recommended as there are not at all reliable and really affect performance. I would advise using jQuery if you absolutely have to align these to the bottom. Also if my answer helped you, I would be grateful if you could mark my answer as accepted. Cheers.

Comment: I boiled-down the solution to the following: http://jsfiddle.net/rkostin/TA39a/ Thanks @andrew-pope.